# JQuery toggle: Repeat the full script for different classes?

Tags: jquery

For a simple toggle based on classes in buttons and p tags, do I have to repeat the script each time? I'm new to JS and trying to learn this. Example of code below!

https://jsfiddle.net/14u4bs6x/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".but1").click(function(){
        $(".type1").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".but2").click(function(){
        $(".type2").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button class="but1">button1</button>
<button class="but2">button2</button>

<p class="type1">#1</p>
<p class="type2">#2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, you don't have to. Add a single class to all elements that you want to toggle.

Comment: In HTML id is unique but classes are not. That means you can have multiple elements with the same class.

Comment: On a page, I want to apply the class to different buttons. Users will want buttons to open alone rather than all at once so same class won't work here I think? Or maybe does it just apply to the clicked button?

Comment: Ok. As per Rory's suggestion below, if I use the same class on the button, but apply different to the p tag and use data target; it'll only require one script. That sounds good! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

If you follow DRY principles then you can solve this by using a common class on the `button` elements to attach your event handler, and setting a `data*` attribute on each one individually to specify the element that should be toggled, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".but").click(function() {
    $("." + $(this).data('target')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but" data-target="type1">button1</button>
<button class="but" data-target="type2">button2</button>

<p class="type1">#1</p>
<p class="type2">#2</p>
```

Alternatively you could set the relationship by their indexes. This means you don't have to change the HTML but is a little more fragile and easily broken.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.but').click(function() {
    $('.type').eq($(this).index('.but')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="but">button1</button>
<button class="but">button2</button>

<p class="type">#1</p>
<p class="type">#2</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory! For the purpose of learning; applying the index will then look at what comes first, and match; kind of like enumerate in python where it uses the index to match?

Comment: I don't know python, but the logic above simply matches the elements on their indexes by class. See http://api.jquery.com/index and http://api.jquery.com/eq for more info

Answer (score 0):

**Simple example:**

```js
function toggle(id){
   $(".type_"+id).toggle();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="toggle('1')">button1</button>
<button onclick="toggle('2')">button2</button>

<p class="type_1">#1</p>
<p class="type_2">#2</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also useful!